# How to apply colour changes to all HTML pages

Tags: css, html, xampp

I am trying to change the colour of the background and text on multiple pages rather than on just one.

The code at the bottom can change the colour and text on one page but DOES NOT CARRY OVER TO OTHERS. How would I do it to all my web pages rather than do it on each page individually every time. I am creating this in Notepad++ and running it in Xampp.

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <script> 
localStorage.setItem('backgroundcolours', 'bgc.options[selectedIndex].value');
localStorage.setItem('myBackgroundColor', '#000088');}
 retrrievecolour() {
var changingText = document.getElementById('changemytext');
var changingbackground = document.getElementById('changemybg');

changingText.style.color = localStorage.backgroundcolours;
changingBackground.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.myBackgroundColor;}</script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

</script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Home page </title>
<div id='changemybg'><div id='changemytext'>
 <script !type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<a class="active" href="Homepage.html">dif</a>
<a class="active" href="newtest.html">Home </a>
<a class="active" href="test.html">test </a>
 </head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
 <form name=backgroundcolour>Background<br><select NAME=backgroundcolouring size= 1
onChange="document.getElementById('changemybg').style.background=backgroundcolouring.options[selectedIndex].value"> 
    <option VALUE="#FFFFFF">White </option> 
    <option VALUE="#F0F0FF">Light Blue </option> 
    <option VALUE="#FFFFD4">Light Yellow </option> 
    <option VALUE="#EEEEEE">Light Gray </option> 
</select></form></td>
<td align="center"><form name=textcolours>Text<br><select NAME=textcolour size=1
onChange="document.getElementById('changemytext').style.color=textcolour.options[selectedIndex].value"> 
    <option VALUE="#000000">Black </option> 
    <option VALUE="#444444">Charcoal </option> 
    <option VALUE="#000088">Dark Blue </option> 
    <option VALUE="#117722">Dark Green </option>
</select></form></td>
</tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's in scripts.js? Please click `<>` and create a [mcve]. You likely need a cookie and a script to read the cookie on each page

Comment: You need to proofread your document markup. Especially around where the document head finishes and the document body begins.

Comment: Ok so i updated the original table that i had which is the bottom code chuck and that is what i used as a template the rest just links to other stuff not important at the moment its just i need help fixing the bottome part if you any ideas pleasse share Thank you @mplungjan

Comment: @Rounin ive updated the code if you know anything that can help with making colour changes on all please share Thank You

Answer (score 1):

CSS styles like `color: #FFFFFF;` and `background-color: #000088` are simple *name-value pairings*, so you can straightforwardly use **HTML5 localStorage** for this.

To set the values:

```
localStorage.setItem('myColor', '#FFFFFF');
localStorage.setItem('myBackgroundColor', '#000088');
```

To retrieve the values:

```
var changingText = document.getElementById('changemytext');
var changingbackground = document.getElementById('changemybg');

changingText.style.color = localStorage.myColor;
changingBackground.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.myBackgroundColor;
```

Comment: Hi where abouts would i add this into my code and as i have a table that uses options how would i alter it to that? Thank you any help would be great @Rounin

Comment: Hi I'm thinking its javascript but when i entered it i couldnt get it working it may be because of the  '#FFFFFF' part,  what would i replace that with to get it to select the value would it be 'value'? sorry if i seem unaware of this datatype as i haven't come across localstorage as of yet Thanks @Rounin

Comment: Use `bgc.options[selectedIndex].value` - as you did above.

Comment: Hi, if you dont mind can you glance through the code and see if im doing something wrong please? Ive tried adding a function to separate the two and tried as just a whole script but didnt manage to get it running If you could it'd be great else if you can not no worries Thank You @Rounin